# Is there anyway that i can create an if statement base on the year display on the HTML Table to compare for another year?

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net

Im trying to create a comparison table for the number of New Students Per Year. In my Json Datai only have 2 column on each object,

here's my Json Data

```
    [
{
    "New_Students": "321",
    "NSYEAR": "2014",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "1923",
    "NSYEAR": "2015",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "293",
    "NSYEAR": "2016",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "29",
    "NSYEAR": "2017",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "524",
    "NSYEAR": "2018",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
}
    ]
```

and here is my current Code in javascript using ajax function

```
       <script>


        $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:37590/get_NSData/' + strCampus, //Change this path to your JSON file.
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",


    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        drawTable(data);
    }
        });

        function drawTable(data) {
    var rows = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        rows.push(drawRow(data[i]));
    }

            $("#personDataTable").append(rows);
        }

        function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.NSYEAR + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.New_Students + "</td>"));

    return row;
        }

</script>
```

my Expected Output should be like this in table form:
SY is School Year
LY is Last Year Data
TY is Todays Year

https://i.stack.imgur.com/by1Zr.jpg "tooltip"

what i want is how will i create another column under LY (Last Year) and will get the value of the Previous Year

as of now with my Code i only get the output of

```
SY    LY   TY      % Inc/Dec
2014       321
2015       1923
2016       293
2017       29
2018       524
```

i want to get the value of TY from Previous Year and be display on the LY Something like this

```
 SY    LY   TY      % Inc/Dec
  2014  8     321
  2015  321   1923
  2016  1923  293
  2017  293   29
  2018  29   524
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ajax works well, try to edit your javascript functions like this :

(Your Json data must be ordered by "year")

I hope it will help you :)

```js
var myData =  [
{
    "New_Students": "321",
    "NSYEAR": "2014",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "1923",
    "NSYEAR": "2015",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "293",
    "NSYEAR": "2016",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "29",
    "NSYEAR": "2017",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "524",
    "NSYEAR": "2018",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
}
    ];
      
       
    
    
    function drawTable(data) {
      var rows = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          rows.push(drawRow(data[i], data[i-1]));
      }

      $("#personDataTable").append(rows);
    }

    function drawRow(rowData, lastyearData) {
      if(lastyearData){
        var row = $("<tr />")
        var percent = (rowData.New_Students-lastyearData.New_Students)/lastyearData.New_Students * 100;
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.NSYEAR + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + lastyearData.New_Students + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.New_Students + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + percent.toFixed(2) + "%" + "</td>"));
      }

      return row;
    }
        
        
        
    drawTable(myData); // move this line to the ajax success function.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SY</th>
      <th>LY</th>
      <th>TY</th>
      <th>%</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="personDataTable">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: done ibra! i have another question, since the output is numbers how i can include commas for thousands? like 1900% to 1,900% something like that

Comment: @PauloFlores You should make a function like this https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/number-currency-formatting-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to set `strCampus` value somexhere...
HTML

```
  <table id="my-Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>SY</th>
        <th>LY</th>
        <th>TY</th>
        <th>% Inc/Dec</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JavaScript

```
var
  url     = 'http://localhost:37590/get_NSData/' + strCampus, // strCampus is not defined
  myTable = document.querySelector('#my-Table tbody'),
  v_LY    = 8;

fetch(url)
.then( r=>r.json())
.then(data=>{
  for(elm of data)
  {
    let
      col = 0,
      row = myTable.insertRow(-1)
      v_TY = parseInt(elm.New_Students),
      percent = ( v_TY -v_LY )/v_LY  * 100;

    row.insertCell(col++).textContent = elm.NSYEAR;
    row.insertCell(col++).textContent = v_LY;
    row.insertCell(col++).textContent = elm.New_Students;
    row.insertCell(col++).textContent = percent.toFixed(2) + ' %'  ;

    v_LY = v_TY;
  }
});
```